# Trying to send data from form to word document as a download?

Tags: php, forms, ms-word

I am a noob so I apologize if this is completely wrong but I thank you guys for your help ahead of time. I am trying to get the data input from my form to automatically insert into a word document which can then be downloaded.

**Here is my form code:**

```
<form class="firstresume.php" method="post">
<input  value="Name *"  name="Your_Name" class="autoclear name-newsletter"     >
<input  value="Email *"  name="Your_Email"  class="email-newsletter"     >
<input  value="Phone *"  name="Your_Phone"  class="phone-newsletter"   >
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="subscribe"  class="button-newsletter">
</form>
```

**Here is my firstresume.php code:**

```
<?php 


    // opens the file you created
$hlines = file("resume.htm");
// creates a new word document
$handle = fopen("C://NewResumé.doc","w+");
// here you replace all the keywords with user's information
foreach($hlines as $hline_num => $hline)
{
    $hline = str_replace("Your_Name",$_REQUEST["Your_Name"],$hline);
        $hline = str_replace("Your_Phone",$_REQUEST["Your_Phone"],$hline);
        $hline = str_replace("Your_Email",$_REQUEST["Your_Email"],$hline);
        fwrite($handle,$hline."\n");
}
?>
```

Comment: What isn't working? Is the information getting added to the doc file? Is the file being downloaded?

Comment: The file you're creating is a plain text file, not a Word document. And the content will be HTML, if that's what's in `resume.htm`. You can't open a file on the client computer with `fopen`, you have to send the file to the script's output, with appropriate headers to make the browser save the file as a download rather than display it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try in your **firstresume.php** file like:

```
<?php
  header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=resume.doc");    
  echo "<html>";
  echo "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">";
  echo "<body>";
  echo "<p>Your Mail: $_REQUEST['Your_Name']</p>";
  echo "<p>Your Phone: $_REQUEST['Your_Phone']</p>";
  echo "<p>Your Email: $_REQUEST['Your_Email']</p>";
  echo "</body>";
  echo "</html>";
?>
```

Comment: This is still HTML, not Word.

Comment: Word can convert this into Doc document, with some slight variations

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [PHPWord](http://phpword.codeplex.com/) project. These guys have a library for PHP that lets you modify (simple) templates and output a new docx file.

Inside the latest version, there are two files (Template.php and Template.docx) that seem to have exactly the code & functionality that you are looking for!